# save the belongsTo model

Tags: cakephp

I've 2 models: **Photo** and **Score**. Each `Photo`, should has a `Score`. So I set `Photo` to belong to `Score`:

```
class Photo extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array('Score');
}
```

The `scores` table has a `photo_id` column. (for its `photo` id)

But, there is a problem.... How to save `photo` and a `score`?

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in your question: "Each `Photo`, should has a `Score`". So you'll have to change your Photo model. This will looks like:

```
class Photo extends AppModel {
      public $actsAs = array('Containable');
      public $hasOne = array('Score');
}
```

You will have to use that model to call saveAll() method which needs to be saved first. So that other associated models may get the value of newly inserted record to treat as a foreign key.

```
$this->Photo->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

Your request array(`$this->request->data`) should looks like:

```
Array(
    [Photo] => Array(
                      [img_name] = abc.jpg
                      [image_group] = cricket
                              ... other fields ...
                    )
    [Score] => Array(
                      [score_gain] => 10
                                  ... other fields ....
                    )
    )
```

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) will help you. How to save associated data. You can also use [saveAssociated()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) method.

I hope it will work for you.